# Updating the wl18xx driver in Yocto

Tags: yocto

I want to update the wl18xx driver in Yocto morty.

Would it be enough to update the recipe to http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-ti/tree/recipes-bsp/wl18xx-fw/wl18xx-fw_8.7.3.bb ?

(I already did it and although I have everything in place it is not working properly: I am able to scan for networks but unable to connect to them - error: wlan0 authentication with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx timed out)

Do I need to change anything on the Linux kernel ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Which is your current version (the one displayed by wlcore at boot time)?

Comment: wl18xx hw: 183x or 180x PG 2.2 ROM 0x11 / FW: 8.2.0.0.232 / fw booted: 8.9.0.0.48

Comment: I meant FW version. That recipe provides the firmware in the form of a binay blob, not the Linux device driver. I think that the driver is already supported by the mainline kernel (since v4.1.x).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any other information in the boot log

Comment: I think you already have the newest FW (fw booted: 8.9.0.0.48). Have you contacted TI? Are you working with `hostapd`?